# Acumatica Smart Panel not showing Empty Data message when opening

Tags: acumatica

I have a smart panel to show a popup on grid column click. This smart panel popup has one grid. This grid is opened without error and display data. But in-case if view doesn't have any data grid empty data message is not displaying. User has to click on grid toolbar refresh button.

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" TypeName="GraphName" PrimaryView="MyOrders" PageLoadBehavior="GoLastRecord" AttributesFound="False" EnableAttributes="False" SuspendUnloading="False">
        <CallbackCommands>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="GotoSteps" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="PXGrid2" />
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>

            <px:PXTab ID="tab" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                <Items>
                    <px:PXTabItem Text="Test Results">
                        <Template>
                            <px:PXGrid ID="PXGrid2" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grid2_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="100%" SkinID="DetailsInTab" SyncPosition="True" TabIndex="2600">

                                <EmptyMsg ComboAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                                    NamedComboMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                                    NamedComboAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                                    FilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                                    FilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                                    NamedFilteredMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                                    NamedFilteredAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                                    AnonFilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                                    AnonFilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."></EmptyMsg>
                                <Levels>
                                    <px:PXGridLevel DataKeyNames="OrderId" DataMember="MyOrders">
                                      <Columns>
                                           <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Steps" Width="180px" LinkCommand="GotoSteps" CommitChanges="true">
                                            </px:PXGridColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </px:PXGridLevel>
                                </Levels>
                                <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
                                <AutoCallBack />
                                <ActionBar>
                                    <CustomItems>
                                        <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Add Sample" Key="cmdSample" CommandName="AddSample" CommandSourceID="ds" DependOnGrid="PXGrid2">
                                            <AutoCallBack>
                                                <Behavior CommitChanges="True" PostData="Page"></Behavior>
                                            </AutoCallBack>
                                        </px:PXToolBarButton>
                                    </CustomItems>
                                </ActionBar>

                            </px:PXGrid>
                        </Template>
                        <AutoCallBack Target="PXGrid2" Command="Refresh">
                            <Behavior RepaintControlsIDs="PXGrid2" />
                        </AutoCallBack>
                    </px:PXTabItem>

                </Items>
                <AutoSize Enabled="True" ></AutoSize>
            </px:PXTab>


<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" runat="Server">
  <px:PXSmartPanel ID="pnlTestSteps" runat="server" Height="400px"  Width="1100px" Caption="Test Steps" CaptionVisible="true" AutoReload="true" LoadOnDemand="true" Key="TestSteps" Style="position: static"
        AutoCallBack-Target="StepsGrid" AutoCallBack-Command="Refresh" DesignView="Content">

        <px:PXGrid ID="StepsGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Inquire"  Height="90%"
            Width="100%" AutoAdjustColumns="true" >
            <EmptyMsg  ComboAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                NamedComboMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                NamedComboAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter or modify parameters above to see records here."
                FilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                FilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                NamedFilteredMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                NamedFilteredAddMessage="No records found as &#39;{0}&#39;.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                AnonFilteredMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."
                AnonFilteredAddMessage="No records found.
Try to change filter to see records here."></EmptyMsg>
            <Levels>
                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="TestSteps" Visible="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Name">
                        </px:PXGridColumn>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Description">
                        </px:PXGridColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>

        </px:PXGrid>

        <px:PXPanel ID="PXPanel7" runat="server" SkinID="Buttons">
            <px:PXButton ID="PXButton9" runat="server" DialogResult="OK" Text="OK"></px:PXButton>
        </px:PXPanel>
    </px:PXSmartPanel>
</asp:Content>
```

C# Graph Code

```
  public PXAction<GraphClass> GoToSteps;
    [PXButton(Tooltip = "Open Popup" )]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Steps")]
    public virtual void gotoSteps() {
      TestSteps.AskExt(true);
      return;
    }
```

Images
[image: Popup With no data don't show empty data message]

[image: Show Empty data message after grid refresh click]

Comment: Have you tried setting SyncPosition="True" on your pop-ups grid?

Comment: Not sure whether calling requestrefresh (before askext) might help - https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/(W(6))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=46fb5aad-4e34-cd36-f955-c15095120d6c

Comment: Could be related to the value of SkinID property used for the grid. Try changing from Inquire to Details.